# How to fix my random button enabler code showing the same order every time?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, uibutton

I have 15 `UIButtons` in my interface, to start with all the buttons are blurred out/disabled. I have code that randomly generates an array of numbers from 1 to 15 these are then used as tags on each of my `UIButton's`. I then loop over the buttons and see if the tags array contains the button tag that I am currently looping over.

```
func assignLabels() {

//Loop through the array of buttons.
for button in buttons {

//Check to see if the array of tags contains the current button tag.
  if tags.contains(button.tag){

    print(button.tag)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.alpha = 1.0
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    switch onStage{
    case 1:
      currentPhoneme = stage1[currentPhonemeNumber]
      button.setTitle(stage1[currentTag], for: .normal)
    //  button.setTitle(button.tag.description, for: .normal)
    case 2:
      currentPhoneme = stage2[currentPhonemeNumber]
      button.setTitle(stage2[currentTag], for: .normal)
    default:
      currentPhoneme = stage1[currentPhonemeNumber]
      button.setTitle(stage1[currentTag], for: .normal)
    }
  }else{
    button.alpha = 0.3
    button.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
  }
  currentTag += 1
  if currentTag == stageCount{
    break
    }
  }
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that as we are looping over the buttons it checks to see if the buttons tag is in the array of tags and subsequently enables that button and assigns it a label. Although this works I get the same order for the buttons every single time the code is called even though the button tags are completely random below is what I get in my interface.
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdGCr.jpg)

What should happen is that each time the function is called the buttons that are enabled should be in a random order across the screen like a different pattern every time. Any help on this behaviour would be great as I am at a loss as to why the order is always the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order is always the same because you are assigning the labels based upon the `currentTag` variable which is in the same order.  Also, `contains` returns the same results no matter the order.

A simple fix would be to reorder the tags of your buttons and use the button's tag instead of `currentTag`:

```
func assignLabels() {

    // New random button tag order
    let newtags = Array(1...buttons.count).shuffled()

    // Loop through the array of buttons.
    for (button, newtag) in zip(buttons, newtags) {

        // Assign new tag to button
        button.tag = newtag

        //Check to see if the array of tags contains the current button tag.
        if tags.contains(button.tag){

            let currentTag = button.tag

            ...

}
```

Be sure to delete this code as it isn't needed:

```
currentTag += 1
if currentTag == stageCount{
    break
}
```

Comment: what if I want to limit the number of buttons that get enabled? the only reason I had the other bit of code was to break out of the loop after enabling X amount of buttons.

Comment: The number of buttons that are enabled is controlled by the `tags` array.  The `tags` array is the random buttons that are enabled, and the `newtags` array is the ordering of the buttons.  You want to loop over **all** of the buttons so that each button gets its new tag and gets enabled/disabled properly.

Comment: Okay I understand so if I loop over all of the buttons how do I check if the button needs to be enabled/disabled? I feel I am taking the wrong approach using Contains because it returns the same order no matter what.

Comment: `contains` is fine.  It tells you if the button should be enabled.  The changes I proposed for your code should do everything you need.  `newtags` is used to assign a new tag to the buttons as you loop over them.  `tags.contains(button.tag)` is used to decide if the button should be enabled and get a new label, or disabled with its title set to blank.